# Django check if form choice is empty

Tags: django, django-templates

In a template how is it possible to check if a **ModelChoiceField** is **empty**?

This is my form:

```
class BatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        this_templates = Template.objects.for_user(user)
        self.fields["templates"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=this_templates, required=False, empty_label=None)
```

Then in my views I want to **not** show the drop down if the **queryset** is empty something like this...

```
{% if not form.templates%}
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    {{ form.templates }}
  </div>
etc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
{% if form.templates.field.choices.queryset.all|length %}

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    {{ form.templates }}
  </div>
```

Comment: for django forms.Form

you can just use

{% if form.templates.field.choices|length %}

Answer (score 2):

Just test the `count` of the queryset in your form field:

```
{% if form.templates.queryset.count %}
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
       {{ form.templates }}
      </div>
    </div>
{%endif%}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's now an `exists` method. This is more efficient than counting for most database backends.

Comment: Some example code would enhance the usefulness of your answer.