# Form of a list of instances

Tags: django

I am missing an idea or a way to handle this in django.

I have a list of instances (class Sample) and I want to present the last 10 of them in a form with a checkbox before... I want to have a button "work on these" to submit the checked instances to a view. This view should present a detailView of the selected instances.

I don't know, how to handle this exactly. Can somebody give me a hint? All I did so far was just creating a form of a instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use formsets to edit more than one model instance at the same time: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: As a suggestion, using "model" to refer to an "instance" is slightly confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) or a [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield).

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
my_list_of_instances = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

This should generate a list of checkbox with your last 10 instances created.

With this you have your form ready to receive your input...just point your action to your view.

Edit:
In case you want to have several forms, one for each instance, you can work with [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). You would not get the checkboxes tho...you would get any change applied to your instances. If you want to have both (checkboxes and formsets) you can use both suggestions, using the checkbox values sent to the server to filter the formsets you are going to save.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The Formset to edit the selected instances is basically the next view, after submitting the first formular. I will try to apply your suggestion and I think it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hey cdvv, your suggestion works fine and helped me so far. I am just looking for a possibility to check the length of my instances within the. Because, at the moment, if there are no instances, I still have the submit button but no checkboxes... Is there a way to check the length or the number of fields?

Comment: Number of fields for the ModelMultipleChoiceField or for the formsets?

Comment: For the ModelMultipleChoiceField. I just want to check in my template if there are nay checkbox or not. With no checkboxes I would print a message, "there is nothing to do".

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640448/django-check-if-form-choice-is-empty  I would use the count tho, is more efficient than calculating the length and is the suggested method on docs.

Comment: This is not working, maybe I miss something. In my view, I create an instance of `form=MyForm()` and return this to my template `return render(request, 'samplesubmission/to_submit.html', {'form': form})`. But within the template I can't find a way to get the count. Maybe because I use forms.Form instead of forms.ModelForm as in the link you suggested

Comment: I tried `{% if form %}` in the template, but this is always true because I get an instance of MyForm. In a shell I was checking which methods my form has. But I could not find any possibility to get a count.

Comment: You need something like {% if form.my_field.queryset.count %}

Comment: But in your example I just get a list of instances, there is no special field, or am I wrong?

Comment: If i understand what you want, you want to avoid rendering when that list is empty, so you check for the number of elements

Comment: yes, this is the exact thing... could not find words to say that :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67473/discussion-between-cdvv7788-and-user7601).